# Prisma working locally but not on Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, nestjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, prisma

I'm trying to build a NestJS server using prisma as orm, it works perfectly fine locally, but not on the EB instance.

Here is the ENV from EB instance :

[image]

here are the logs from the EB instance trying to run :

```
Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/prisma.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m2#033[0m:#033[93m10#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2305: #033[0mModule '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'PrismaClient'.
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m2#033[0m import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m #033[0m #033[91m         ~~~~~~~~~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/prisma.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m7#033[0m:#033[93m16#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2339: #033[0mProperty '$connect' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m7#033[0m     await this.$connect();
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m #033[0m #033[91m               ~~~~~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/prisma.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m11#033[0m:#033[93m10#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2339: #033[0mProperty '$on' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m11#033[0m     this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m  #033[0m #033[91m         ~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/providers/provider.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m2#033[0m:#033[93m10#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2305: #033[0mModule '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'Provider'.
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m2#033[0m import { Provider, Prisma, User } from "@prisma/client";
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m #033[0m #033[91m         ~~~~~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/providers/provider.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m2#033[0m:#033[93m20#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2305: #033[0mModule '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'Prisma'.
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m2#033[0m import { Provider, Prisma, User } from "@prisma/client";
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m #033[0m #033[91m                   ~~~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/providers/provider.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m2#033[0m:#033[93m28#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2305: #033[0mModule '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'User'.
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m2#033[0m import { Provider, Prisma, User } from "@prisma/client";
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m #033[0m #033[91m                           ~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/providers/provider.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m13#033[0m:#033[93m31#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2339: #033[0mProperty 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m13#033[0m             await this.prisma.user.update({
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m  #033[0m #033[91m                              ~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/providers/provider.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m22#033[0m:#033[93m31#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2339: #033[0mProperty 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
    Oct 14 20:09:49 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m22#033[0m             await this.prisma.user.update({
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m  #033[0m #033[91m                              ~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/providers/provider.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m41#033[0m:#033[93m24#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2339: #033[0mProperty 'provider' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m41#033[0m     return this.prisma.provider.findMany({
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m  #033[0m #033[91m                       ~~~~~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/user/user.controller.ts#033[0m:#033[93m3#033[0m:#033[93m10#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2305: #033[0mModule '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'User'.
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m3#033[0m import { User as UserModel} from '@prisma/client';
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m #033[0m #033[91m         ~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/user/user.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m3#033[0m:#033[93m10#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2305: #033[0mModule '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'User'.
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m3#033[0m import { User, Prisma } from '@prisma/client';
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m #033[0m #033[91m         ~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/user/user.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m3#033[0m:#033[93m16#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2305: #033[0mModule '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'Prisma'.
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m3#033[0m import { User, Prisma } from '@prisma/client';
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m #033[0m #033[91m               ~~~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/user/user.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m12#033[0m:#033[93m24#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2339: #033[0mProperty 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m12#033[0m     return this.prisma.user.findUnique({
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m  #033[0m #033[91m                       ~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/user/user.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m25#033[0m:#033[93m24#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2339: #033[0mProperty 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m25#033[0m     return this.prisma.user.findMany({
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m  #033[0m #033[91m                       ~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/user/user.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m35#033[0m:#033[93m24#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2339: #033[0mProperty 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m35#033[0m     return this.prisma.user.create({
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m  #033[0m #033[91m                       ~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/user/user.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m45#033[0m:#033[93m24#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2339: #033[0mProperty 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m45#033[0m     return this.prisma.user.update({
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m  #033[0m #033[91m                       ~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[96msrc/user/user.service.ts#033[0m:#033[93m52#033[0m:#033[93m24#033[0m - #033[91merror#033[0m#033[90m TS2339: #033[0mProperty 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m52#033[0m     return this.prisma.user.delete({
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: #033[7m  #033[0m #033[91m                       ~~~~#033[0m
    Oct 14 20:09:50 ip-172-31-7-181 web: Found 17 error(s).
    Oct 14 20:10:05 ip-172-31-7-181 web: > b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-area-maxence.pellouin@1.0.0 start
    Oct 14 20:10:05 ip-172-31-7-181 web: > cd server && npm install && npm run start
    Oct 14 20:10:55 ip-172-31-7-181 web: > b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-area-maxence.pellouin@1.0.0 start
    Oct 14 20:10:55 ip-172-31-7-181 web: > cd server && npm install && npm run start
```

[here is the full log](https://pastebin.com/4LjQfkHJ)

As i've said, it works perfectly fine locally, the source is pulled from a github and i've tried to clone it and try manually to see if the branch was working, and it does.

[also, from prisma documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/caveats-when-deploying-to-aws-platforms)

I've added a .npmrc file to the root of the app with the following property

```
unsafe-perm=true
```

to let prisma generate client code in node_modules.

I can't see what I'm missing, thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Do you run `prisma generate` in your postinstall?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, yes i run npx prisma generate on startup with package.json start script

Comment: Is your code open source? If yes, could you share the repo so that I could try to replicate this?